# ajax show new post slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css

I use jquery code like below

```
$('form#new-post').ajaxForm({
    success:function(html){
       $('#post-list').prepend(html);
    }
 });
```

It show the post at once, but I want an animation on it, just like slide down.

I want a simplest solution on it, can css3 do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your html has a container DIV this will work:

```
$('form#new-post').ajaxForm({
    url: "mypage.html",
    success:function(html){
       var html = $(html).hide();
       $('#post-list').prepend(html);
       html.slideDown();
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Feel free to switch that animation with whatever you want.

```
$('form#new-post').ajaxForm({
    success:function(html){
       $('#post-list').hide().prepend(html).fadeIn();
    }
 });
```